# Facebook server-sent event with "live comment" endpoint requires user_videos scope

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-video

I am implementing a sever-sent event client to get real time comments of a Facebook live video.

According to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments/), it only requires the token to have `publish_video`. But it keeps returning error 401.

If I request `user_videos` scope, the error will not occur anymore and I can receive comments of the live video.

Is it a facebook bug?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone might have resolved this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266807/facebook-api-get-live-comment