# facebook api get live comment

Tags: facebook, live-streaming

as facebook mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments) for get live comment

and i do like what they said

```
var source = new EventSource("https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/2025853151054872/live_comments?access_token=MY TOKEN HERE&fields=from{name,id},message");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
console.log(event);
  // Do something with event.message for example
};
```

this will give me 401 error and as they mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments) at the end of page its mean

> Unauthorized
>
> Make sure your app has the right permissions and that the access token is valid.

so i checked my access token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

and its give me this result

```
 Metadata   {"sso":"chrome_custom_tab","auth_type":"rerequest"}
 Valid  True
 Data Access Expires    1560876206 (in about 3 months)
 Origin Mobile Web Faceweb
 Scopes email, publish_video, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile
```

i don't know why there is error and every thing its right

also i test same url with android library [library](https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android)
and same its give me error

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution seems facebook need more permission and its

`user_videos` permission but they doesn't mentioned that

Comment: Where is this? Not able to find this permission in Graph API explorer